# Command line FTP download latest files

Tags: command-line, bash, ftp

I am trying to use the command line ftp to download files from a specific date and onwards. Is there a simple solution for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are bound to using the plain `ftp` client, you will have to do some scripting. I would use `wget` instead. It is available for every platform and can do this using a command line option (see `-N`).

Comment: Hmm, I just ended up doing some simple scripting. Thanks!